# Use WTForms RadioField subfields to display an image in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am using a WTForm form to try to transmit the path to an image I want to display in HTML. My form looks basically like this

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import RadioField

class SelectStyleForm(FlaskForm):
     images = RadioField('style image.',
                         choices=[(value1, label1),(value2, label2),...])
```

My goal is to iterate over the different choices to display the image associated to each path next to the corresponding radio button. My HTML template looks like this :

```
 {% block content %}

 <form method=post>
      {% for subfield in styleform.images %}
           <td>{{subfield}}</td>
           <p>{{subfield.label}}</p>
           <img src="{{url_for('data_path', filename=subfield.label)}}"/>
      {% endfor %}
 </form>
 {% enblock %}
```

right now, the radio button is displayed along with the name of the file (which is written in the `<p>` tag), but I can't find a way to have that same name affected to `filename`.

Right now, the value it refers to is :

```
<label for="images-1">value1</label>
```

Is there a way tp affect the "correct" value in the `url_for` function ?
Please note that I would also accept a solution for which the `value` part of the different choices is used, as they are supposed to be the same path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrigth, by fiddling around with the different methods, I discovered that each subfield has a `data` attribute that stores the string of the `label` part.

So my code works simply by changing the source of the image :

```
<img src="{{url_for('data_path', filename=subfield.data)}}"/>
```

My best guess is that the `.label` attribute is already attributed to something else in the `url_for` function and that prevents it to access the string corresponding to the label.

Feel free to correct me if I am wrong or do not hesitate to post a more detailed answer !

Comment: I believe the `data` field actually shows the _value_ not the _label_.  My guess is that in your case, you've set each value to match the its corresponding label.

Answer (score 0):

So far this is the solution that worked for me

```
 <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/' + subfield.id + '.png' )}}"/>
```

Which will give you  URL for image for the first question and first option looking like  like this
/static/images/question1-0.png

Why **static**: as of 2023 images are stored in **/static/images/**

**subfield.id** - so far this is the only one that worked.
I've tried with `subfield.label` and it got me something like this:
as URL: `/static/%3Clabel%20for=%22question1-0%22%3EOften-Q1%3C/label%3E`

`subfield.value` gave me `/static/.png`
but subfield.id seems to work, as is unique for each subfield, and so far you don't need to assign it, it's auto assigned by flask.

### **Extraction of the code that may interest you:**

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import RadioField, SubmitField


class SurveyForm(FlaskForm):
# example = RadioField('Label', choices=[('value','subfield.label'),('value','subfield.label')])
    
        question1 = RadioField('Question 1', choices=[('Often-A1', 'Often-Q1'), ('Sometimes-A1', 'Sometimes-Q1'), ('Never-A1', 'Never-Q1')])
```

---

**survey.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('survey') }}" method="post">
          {{ form.csrf_token }}
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                 <h4>{{ form.question1.label }}:</h4>
                   {% for subfield in form.question1 %}
                      <div class="form-check">
                          {{ subfield(class="form-check-input") }}
                          {{ subfield.label(class="form-check-label") }}
                          <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/' + subfield.id + '.png' )}}"/>
                                
                      </div>
                  {% endfor %}
              </div>
          </div>
   {{ form.submit }} </form>
```